# automatic calling custom converter of raw pointers A* <-> B*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Is it possible to define a custom converter (`converter1<T>` and `converter2`) between different types of raw pointer `A*` and `B*`,
then make all functions (`fa()` and `fb()`) in a certain class
use an appropriate converter (`converter1<T>` or `converter2`)?

In short, I want the program to convert `A*` to `B*` and vice versa USING my custom functions.
 I wish it would do that automatically for my convenience.

```
class Manager{
    void fb(B* b){ /** something complex       */ }
    void fa(A* a){ /** different thing complex */ }
    void testCase(){
        A* a=   ... ;  
        fa(a);  
        fb(a);  //automatic convert to B* using "converter2" (wish)
        B* b=   ... ;
        fa(b);  //automatic convert to A* using "converter1" (wish)
        fb(b);
    }
    template<class T> T* converter1(B* b){  //hardcoded, non-static.
        return this->getId<T>(b);   
        //^^^ just an example to show how custom it is,
        //    currently T=A
    }
    B* converter2(A* a){  //hardcoded
        return a->getB();   
        //^^^ just an example to show how custom it is.
    }
}
```

The real case has many `A` - `A1`, `A2`, `A3` and so on.
`A` and `B` are not derived from each other.

I wish there is a way.  I think about constructor of pointer.

Comment: Are A and B derived from each other?

Comment: No, they are not related class.  Thank, I forgot, I will add it to the question.

Comment: Short answer: No, that's not possible.

Comment: But they are convertible through a pointer??

Comment: Converting one unrelated type to another via a pointer cast is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible.

Pointers are built-in types and only built-in conversions between built-in types exist. User-defined conversions only work for user-defined class types.

You may want to switch to your own brand of smart pointers to handle this.

Comment: "your own brand of smart pointers" <-----   Will it be more expensive (comparing to my code), if I use `class APtr{ A* a; }` ?

Comment: @javaLover Probably not. Compilers are good at optimizing away such things. Try it and see.

Answer (score 4):

through references (or smart pointers) it's more possible:

```
struct A {};
struct B {};


A& convert_to_a(A& a) { return a; }
A convert_to_a(B const& b) { 
    // makes a new A from a B
    return A(); 
}

B& convert_to_b(B& b) { return b; }
B convert_to_b(A const& a) { return B(); }


struct Manager
{
  template<class T>
  void fa(T&& t) { 
    auto&& a = convert_to_a(t); 
    // do something with a
    (void)a;
  }

  template<class T>
    void fb(T&& t) { 
    auto&& b = convert_to_b(t); 
    // do something with b
    (void)b;
  }

};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  Manager m;

  m.fa(a);
  m.fb(a);
  m.fa(b);
  m.fb(b); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible the way you want it.
Anyway, you can use a catch-all function and a bunch of traits to simulate it.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

template<typename T>
A* ToAConverter(T*) = delete;

template<>
A* ToAConverter<B>(B *b) {
    // just an example
    return new A;
}

struct Manager{
    void fa(A* a){ std::cout << "fa" << std::endl; }

    template<typename T>
    void fa(T *t) {
        std::cout << "convert and forward" << std::endl;
        fa(ToAConverter<T>(t));
    }

    void testCase(){
        A *a = new A;  
        fa(a);  
        B *b = new B;
        fa(b); 
    }
};

int main() {
    Manager m;
    m.testCase();
}
```

In case you haven't defined a `converter` for a specific type, you'll receive a compile-time error.
As you can see, you have no longer to call explicitly the converter when you invoke `fa`.